# AWS Appsync/Cognito Authentication Security

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, jwt, amazon-cognito, aws-appsync

I have an iOS app that uses [AWSMobileClient](https://aws-amplify.github.io/aws-sdk-ios/docs/reference/AWSMobileClient/index.html) and AppSync with [AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/security-authz.html) authorization to authorize users who are signing into our app.

I have a question regarding security. After doing a little proxy debugging with Charles Proxy, it appears as though you can easily get the Session's IDToken by Base64 decoding the header sent from the client to Cognito when a user first signs in. Then, once a user is signed in, the same IDToken is used as the Authorization header when making an AppSync Query/Mutation.

How is this not a security vulnerability? Couldn't an attacker easily decode the JWT token, obtain the IDToken, and then make subsequent requests (queries/mutations) using that ID Token?